# QuickView not working after load product Using infinite scroll Magento 2

Tags: magento2, requirejs, quickview, infinte-scroll

I am using Weltpixel Quick View extension and it is working fine.But there is an issue when products loads using infinite scroll.After loads products using infinite scroll , quick view stops working.There is an issue related to the JS function.Can you guys let me know which quick function i have to use in the infinite scroll JS file?

This is my URL:
http://45.56.70.30/pospaper/thermal-paper-rolls/all-thermal-paper.html
You can check from here.Once the products loads , quick view stops working.

I am using Strategy Infinite Scroll.
https://github.com/Strategery-Inc/Magento2-InfiniteScroll
This infinite scroll also working fine.

**Infintie scroll Js file path:**

https://github.com/Strategery-Inc/Magento2-InfiniteScroll/blob/master/view/frontend/web/js/infinitescroll.js

**Weltpixel Quick View JS file**

http://45.56.70.30/pospaper/weltpixel_quickview.js

**This is the script which used in phtml file.**

```
<script>
    requirejs(['jquery', 'weltpixel_quickview' ],
        function   ($, quickview) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.weltpixel-quickview').bind('click', function() {
                    var prodUrl = $(this).attr('data-quickview-url');
                    if (prodUrl.length) {
                        quickview.displayContent(prodUrl);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    window.weltpixel_quickview = {"baseUrl":"http:\/\/45.56.70.30\/pospaper\/","closeSeconds":"5","showMiniCart":"1","showShoppingCheckoutButtons":"0"};
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am also using infinite scroll on category pages and search result page. I have managed to work by changing the following file:

> app/code/WeltPixel/Quickview/view/frontend/templates/initialize.phtml

Replacing the whole code with below code:

```
<?php
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var $block \WeltPixel\Quickview\Block\Initialize */
?>
<script>
    requirejs(['jquery', 'weltpixel_quickview' ],
        function   ($, quickview) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#maincontent').on('click', '.weltpixel-quickview', function() {
                    var prodUrl = $(this).attr('data-quickview-url');
                    if (prodUrl.length) {
                        quickview.displayContent(prodUrl);
                    }
                });
            });
        });

    window.weltpixel_quickview = <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo \Zend_Json::encode($block->getConfig()); ?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

1. First I installed the Scroll.
2. After that the Quickview with that changing.